# Is there a simple way to check all CheckBox items in custimize BaseAdapter in android?

Tags: android

1. I defined a customize ImageAdapter with CheckBox control, I hope to click a button to check all CheckBox items in the ImageAdapter. Is there a simple way to do that?
2. And more, I hope to get all checked CheckBox items?  how to do that ?

BTW, at present, I use a arrary  `boolean[] thumbnailsselection` to do that, but I think that control `CheckBox checkbox` should to remember itself checked stutus! So maybe there is a simle way to do that.

**Call**

```
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);        
imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

**Source**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public boolean[] thumbnailsselection;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }   


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photogalleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);           
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;


            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                    SetSelectedAndTotal();
                }
            });

            holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                }
            });           

            return convertView;
        }

    }


    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean flag = true;
```

Now on the button "select all" click, switch flag value:

```
flag = !flag;
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

**In your adapter** Declare variables:

```
    public ArrayList<String> checkedList;
    boolean flag = true;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        checkedList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

In the getView method:

```
...
    final ViewHolder holder;
...
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(flag);
    holder.id = position;


    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                checkedList.add(Integer.toString(holder.id));
            } else {
                checkedList.remove(Integer.toString(holder.id));
            }
        }
    });
...
```

Adding those functions into your adapter

```
    public void setSelectAll() {
        flag = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setDeselectAll() {
        flag = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedList() {
        return checkedList;
    }
```

From your activity, just call `adapter.setSelectAll()` in `onClick` of your button, and `adapter.getCheckedList()` to handle your checked items.

Hope this work!

Comment: And more, can I get the checked CheckBox items with your way?