# Hide or Show checkboxes inside Custom grid adapter for all Positions

Tags: java, android, gridview

[image: Add To Cart -Image]

I have to hide all the checkboxes for every [Position] product until User click button. When ever user clicks button check boxes will be show to select items for delete. Only check box will appear to change not whole grid view.

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ProductCount> productCounts;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageButton plusButton;
    private ImageButton minusButton;
    private CheckBox selectToDelete;
    private onDeleteCartItem onDeleteCartItem = null;


    public CartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductCount> productCounts, onDeleteCartItem selectChangeListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productCounts = productCounts;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.onDeleteCartItem = selectChangeListener;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(productCounts!=null)
            return productCounts.size();
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if(productCounts!=null && position >=0 && position<getCount())
            return productCounts.get(position);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if(productCounts!=null && position >=0 && position<getCount()){
            ProductCount temp = productCounts.get(position);
            return productCounts.indexOf(temp);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public class ProductsListHolder{
        public ImageView cart_item_img;
        public TextView cart_item_desc;
        public TextView cart_item_count;
        public TextView cart_item_price_tag;
        public TextView cart_item_price;
        public ImageButton cart_item_minus;
        public ImageButton cart_item_plus;


    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ProductsListHolder productsListHolder;
        if(view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_adapter, parent, false);
            productsListHolder = new ProductsListHolder();
            productsListHolder.cart_item_img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_img);
            productsListHolder.cart_item_desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_desc);
            productsListHolder.cart_item_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_count);
            productsListHolder.cart_item_price_tag = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_price_tag);
            productsListHolder.cart_item_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_price);
            plusButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_plus);
            minusButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_minus);
            selectToDelete = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.select_to_delete);
            selectToDelete.setTag(position);
            view.setTag(productsListHolder);
        }
        else{
            productsListHolder = (ProductsListHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        final ProductCount cat = productCounts.get(position);
        selectToDelete.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    if(onDeleteCartItem != null){
                        onDeleteCartItem.onSelectToDelete((Integer)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int itemcount = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemcount = productCounts.get(position).getCount();
                productCounts.get(position).setCount(itemcount-1);
                setProduct(position,productsListHolder,cat);
            }
        });
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int itemcount = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemcount = productCounts.get(position).getCount();
                productCounts.get(position).setCount(itemcount+1);
                setProduct(position,productsListHolder,cat);
            }
        });

        setProduct(position,productsListHolder,cat);
        return view;
    }

    private void setProduct(int position, final ProductsListHolder productsListHolder, ProductCount pCount) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(pCount.products.getImageResours()).into(new Target(){
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                productsListHolder.cart_item_img.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            }
        });
        productsListHolder.cart_item_desc.setText(pCount.getProducts().getDescription());
        productsListHolder.cart_item_price_tag.setText((String.valueOf(pCount.getCount()).concat(" x Rs. ").concat(String.valueOf((pCount.products.getPrice())))));
        productsListHolder.cart_item_price.setText("Rs. ".concat(String.valueOf(pCount.getCount()* pCount.products.getPrice())));
        productsListHolder.cart_item_count.setText(String.valueOf(pCount.getCount()));
    }
    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just handling your checkBox in your adapter because you got the position then can hide/show, `OnClickListener`, `OnCheckedChangeListener` however you want.
Reference to my answer here: [Is there a simple way to check all CheckBox items in custimize BaseAdapter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663213/is-there-a-simple-way-to-check-all-checkbox-items-in-custimize-baseadapter-in-an/33663277#33663277)

Comment: How can I do this while I am just updating/initializing grid adapter only once.
I need to show only the time when user clicks cancel button. as above in picture. Cancel button **X** is not part of grid adapter.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can call the adapter's method inside your "X button OnClick".